# Creating a custom exception class and custom handler class in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, exception

Before I get to the code, let me explain my aim. My web app displays vehicles for sale. I have a need for a custom 404 page that will display 12 of the latest vehicles added to the database if the user tries to access a page that doesn't exist.

I have the following...

App\Exceptions\CustomException.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class CustomException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

App\Exceptions\CustomHandler.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use App\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle\EloquentVehicle;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class CustomHandler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $vehicle;

    public function __construct(Container $container, EloquentVehicle $vehicle)
    {
        parent::__construct($container);

        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
    }

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        $exception = Handler::prepareException($exception);

        if($exception instanceof CustomException) {
            return $this->showCustomErrorPage();
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    public function showCustomErrorPage()
    {
        $recentlyAdded = $this->vehicle->fetchLatestVehicles(0, 12);

        return View::make('errors.404Custom')->with('recentlyAdded', $recentlyAdded);
    }
}
```

To test this I added

> throw new CustomException();

to my controller but it doesn't bring up the 404Custom view. What do I need to do to get this working?

**UPDATE**: Just a note for anyone who's bound their class to their model. You'll get a BindingResolutionException if you try to access a function in your class using:

**app(MyClass::class)**->functionNameGoesHere();

To get around this simply create a variable in the same way you would bind your class to the Container in your service provider.

My code looks like this:

```
protected function showCustomErrorPage()
{
    $eloquentVehicle = new EloquentVehicle(new Vehicle(), new Dealer());
    $recentlyAdded = $eloquentVehicle->fetchLatestVehicles(0, 12);

    return view()->make('errors.404Custom')->with('recentlyAdded', $recentlyAdded);
}
```

Amit's version

```
protected function showCustomErrorPage()
{
    $recentlyAdded = app(EloquentVehicle::class)->fetchLatestVehicles(0, 12);

    return view()->make('errors.404Custom')->with('recentlyAdded', $recentlyAdded);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel calls the `render` function of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. So overriding it will not work.

You have to add it in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class only.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle\EloquentVehicle;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof CustomException) {
            return $this->showCustomErrorPage();
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    protected function showCustomErrorPage()
    {
        $recentlyAdded = app(EloquentVehicle::class)->fetchLatestVehicles(0, 12);

        return view()->make('errors.404Custom')->with('recentlyAdded', $recentlyAdded);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you re-use lots of code by building vendor packages for yourself, then it may be helpful to make your own Handler class and reference it from the project/bootstrap/app.php .  That way you can keep alll your code in packages and use composer to distribute your updates.

Answer (score 37):

**Step 1:** Create a custom Exception

`php artisan make:exception CustomException`

**Step 2:** Include that exception in your code

`use App\Exceptions\CustomException;`

Pass your error to that Exception

```
if($somethingerror){
  throw new CustomException('Your error message');          
}
```

**Step 3:** Handle your exception in CustomException file in **report()** and **render()** methods

For example, if I want display the error as JSON format

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;
use Exception;
class CustomException extends Exception
{   
    public function render($request)
    {       
        return response()->json(["error" => true, "message" => $this->getMessage()]);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In new versions of Laravel, you can create a custom handler using this command:

```
php artisan make:exception CustomException
```

Then you should call these methods "**report()**, **render()**" inside your custom handler and they will override the existing ones in the `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

report() used if you want to log the errors.

render() used if you want to redirect back with error or return HTTP response (like your own Blade file) or if you're building an API.

For more information, you can check [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#renderable-exceptions).