# Laravel 5 throw just exception error on its own

Tags: laravel-5

I am running the following query :

```
$data2 = DB::table('affiliate')->where('affID','=', $collectData['AffiliateID'])->where('AffStatus','==',1)->get();
    if (count($data2)) {
        throw new Exception('Affiliate Paused');
    }
```

When there is an error, it throws an exception , but a whole lot of other error information as well, please see below. How do i throw only the Exception error and nothing else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ondblclick="var t = event.target; if (t.title && !t.href) { var f = t.innerHTML; t.innerHTML = t.title; t.title = f; }">
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="ErrorException">ErrorException</abbr> in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/routes/web.php line 199">web.php line 199</a>:</span>
                            <span class="exception_message">Undefined index: AffiliateIDs</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <ol class="traces list_exception">
       <li> in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/routes/web.php line 199">web.php line 199</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->handleError(8, 'Undefined index: AffiliateIDs', '/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/routes/web.php', 199, <em>array</em>('collectData' => <em>array</em>('SubID2' => '99999999', 'LeadSource' => 'testdomain.com', 'Address1' => 'Flat 5, Jacobs Court', 'Address2' => 'Kyrle Street', 'AddressFrom' => '2014-04-01', 'AddressStatus' => 'private tenant', 'AffiliateID' => 'StressTest', 'APIKey' => '46AB77889181713BFB7200EA7479636009284C8F44536192947870E4AA8F0053', 'AffiliateReference' => 'MW0010', 'BankAccount' => '23411931', 'BankSortCode' => '203964', 'Consent' => '1', 'County' => 'Herefordshire', 'DebitCard' => 'visa debit', 'DOB' => '1983-07-31', 'Email' => 'slawekk83@googlemail.com', 'Employer' => 'Cargill', 'Position' => 'Other', 'ExpenseCredit' => '20', 'ExpenseRentMortgage' => '20', 'ExpenseUtilitiesBills' => '20', 'ExpenseTransport' => '70', 'ExpenseFood' => '60', 'ExpenseRegularOutgoings' => '67', 'FirstName' => 'Slawomir', 'IncomeFollowing' => '2017-06-30', 'IncomeFrequency' => 'last working day of month', 'IncomeFrom' => '2014-04-01', 'IncomeMethod' => 'direct into account', 'IncomeMonthly' => '1400', 'IncomeNext' => '2017-05-31', 'IncomeSource' => 'full time employment', 'Industry' => 'not applicable', 'IPAddress' => '94.197.120.118', 'HomePhone' => '01432352400', 'LastName' => 'Kozlowski', 'Live' => '1', 'LoanAmount' => '150', 'MaxTime' => '180', 'MinPrice' => '5', 'Browser' => 'Safari', 'MobilePhone' => '07397764024', 'OPTIN' => '1', 'Postcode' => 'HR1 2EW', 'Title' => 'Mr', 'Town' => 'HEREFORD', 'WorkPhone' => '01432352400', 'SubID1' => '11532', 'SubID3' => <em>null</em>, 'Dependants' => '1', 'MaritalStatus' => 'single', 'LoanReason' => 'pay bills', 'Company' => 'MDXSOLUTIONS', 'Energy' => 'British Gas', 'LoanDuration' => '3', 'Guarantor' => '0', 'Debt5K' => '1'), 'dataCheck1' => <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Support\Collection">Collection</abbr>))) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/routes/web.php line 199">web.php line 199</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->{closure}() in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php line 190">Route.php line 190</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->runCallable() in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php line 163">Route.php line 163</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->run() in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 559">Router.php line 559</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 30">Pipeline.php line 30</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php line 41">SubstituteBindings.php line 41</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings">SubstituteBindings</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65">VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken">VerifyCsrfToken</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49">ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession">ShareErrorsFromSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php line 64">StartSession.php line 64</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession">StartSession</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php line 59">EncryptCookies.php line 59</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies">EncryptCookies</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 102">Pipeline.php line 102</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 561">Router.php line 561</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->runRouteWithinStack(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 520">Router.php line 520</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatchToRoute(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 498">Router.php line 498</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 174">Kernel.php line 174</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 30">Pipeline.php line 30</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php line 30">TransformsRequest.php line 30</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest">TransformsRequest</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php line 30">TransformsRequest.php line 30</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest">TransformsRequest</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php line 27">ValidatePostSize.php line 27</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize">ValidatePostSize</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46">CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 102">Pipeline.php line 102</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 149">Kernel.php line 149</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 116">Kernel.php line 116</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/comloantreedata/public_html/api/public/index.php line 54">index.php line 54</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523610/creating-a-custom-exception-class-and-custom-handler-class-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, this will only echo out your error response. It does not deal with exceptions at all, it will just stop the script from running any further.

```
$data2 = DB::table('affiliate')->where('affID','=', $collectData['AffiliateID'])->where('AffStatus','==',1)->get();
        if (!count($data2)) {
            echo 'Affiliate ID is incorrect or not active';
            exit();
        }
```