# Thrown object must be an instance of 'Exception' or 'Throwable' in PhpStorm and Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-10

I'm getting *"Thrown object must be an instance of 'Exception' or 'Throwable'"* in PhpStorm. As shown on the picture here:

[image: Thrown object must be an instance of 'Exception' or 'Throwable']

My code works as expected, but for some reason it's showing the above message.

Is there a solution to fix this in Laravel without disabling the message in PhpStorm?

Comment: Please show the code definition for AuthApiException

Comment: @anyber I have used the default Laravel stub without additional code to avoid potential issues. The default comes with `class AuthApiException extends Exception`, so I have even tried with `class AuthApiException extends \Exception`

Comment: looks like custom exception class for handling api request, doesn't comes with laravel default.

Comment: Take a look a this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69386686/4650866

Comment: @Vipertecpro Thank you for the reply. I already have a code like that. The exception is working fine. I only have an issue with PhpStorm which is highlighting the code like it was shown in the picture. The funny thing is that while I was working on it initially a few days ago, I didn't have any highlightings, so everything was ok.

Comment: @iRakic Will it work OK if you use `File | Invalidate caches...`, restart the IDE and let it reindex the project?

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much! That helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: @iRakic Glade you worked it out, yes sometimes phpstrom doesn't index currently created files so we may need to clear cache to index all files.

Comment: Please upvote comments or answers that helped you.
@LazyOne Please submit your comments as an answer, so can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is what @LazyOne suggested.
In PhpStorm, select from the main menu File -> Invalidate Caches, then click Invalidate and Restart.